# Is there a more efficient way to calculate the power set of an array?

Tags: vba, excel, set, powerset

This is my current implementation using bits:

```
Function Array_PowerSet(Self)
    Array_PowerSet = Array()
    PowerSetUpperBound = -1
    For Combination = 1 To 2 ^ (UBound(Self) - LBound(Self)) ' I don't want the null set
        Subset = Array()
        SubsetUpperBound = -1
        For NthBit = 0 To Int(WorksheetFunction.Log(Combination, 2))
            If Combination And 2 ^ NthBit Then
                SubsetUpperBound = SubsetUpperBound + 1
                ReDim Preserve Self(0 To SubsetUpperBound)
                Subset(SubsetUpperBound) = Self(NthBit)
            End If
        Next
        PowerSetUpperBound = PowerSetUpperBound + 1
        ReDim Preserve Array_PowerSet(0 To PowerSetUpperBound)
        Array_PowerSet(PowerSetUpperBound) = Subset
    Next
End Function
```

Please ignore the abuse of Variants. `Array_Push` and `Array_Size` should be self-explanatory.

Previously, I was generating a binary string for each combination, but that involved calling another function which wasn't very efficient.

Aside from using less Variants and moving external function calls inside, is there any way I can make this more efficient?

EDIT: Here's a fully independent version.

```
Function Array_PowerSet(Self As Variant) As Variant
    Dim PowerSet() As Variant, PowerSetIndex As Long, Size As Long, Combination As Long, NthBit As Long
    PowerSetIndex = -1: Size = UBound(Self) - LBound(Self) + 1
    ReDim PowerSet(0 To 2 ^ Size - 2) ' Don't want null set

    For Combination = 1 To 2 ^ Size - 1
        Dim Subset() As Variant, SubsetIndex As Long: SubsetIndex = -1

        For NthBit = 0 To Int(WorksheetFunction.Log(Combination, 2))
            If Combination And 2 ^ NthBit Then
                SubsetIndex = SubsetIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve Subset(0 To SubsetIndex)
                Subset(SubsetIndex) = Self(NthBit)
            End If
        Next

        PowerSetIndex = PowerSetIndex + 1
        PowerSet(PowerSetIndex) = Subset
    Next

    Array_PowerSet = PowerSet
End Function
```

And a test:

```
Dim Input_() As Variant, Output_() As Variant, Subset As Variant, Value As Variant
Input_ = Array(1, 2, 3)
Output_ = Array_PowerSet(Input_)

For Each Subset In Output_
    Dim StringRep As String: StringRep = "{"

    For Each Value In Subset
        StringRep = StringRep & Value & ", "
    Next

    Debug.Print Left$(StringRep, Len(StringRep) - 2) & "}"
Next
```

Comment: Why not give all of the relevant code and make it a [mcve]? `Array_Push` might be the bottleneck (e.g. if it is a wrapper for `ReDim Preserve` to add another element then that is very inefficient since you are repeatedly copying elements).

Comment: *Array_Push and Array_Size should be self-explanatory.* - not if you are asking for assistance on a coding forum...

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

Since the number of subsets grows exponentially, no algorithm is truly efficient, although there is room for improvement in what you are doing:

`ReDim Preserve`, when used to extend an array by a single item, is inefficient since it involves creating a new array with 1 more space and then copying the old elements to the new array. It is better to pre-allocate enough space and then trim it down to size:

```
Function PowerSet(Items As Variant) As Variant
    'assumes that Items is a 0-based array
    'returns a 0-based jagged array of subsets of Items
    'where each subset is a 0-based array

    Dim PS As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    Dim subset As Variant

    n = 1 + UBound(Items) 'cardinality of the base set
    ReDim PS(0 To 2 ^ n - 2)
    For i = 1 To 2 ^ n - 1
        subset = Array()
        ReDim subset(0 To n - 1)
        k = -1 'will be highest used index of the subset
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            If i And 2 ^ j Then
                k = k + 1
                subset(k) = Items(j)
            End If
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve subset(0 To k)
        PS(i - 1) = subset
    Next i
    PowerSet = PS
End Function
```

A test function:

```
Sub test()
    Dim stuff As Variant, subsets As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    stuff = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
    subsets = PowerSet(stuff)
    For i = LBound(subsets) To UBound(subsets)
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "{" & Join(subsets(i), ",") & "}"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Would ArrayLists be a better option for this task? I could just just call ToArray on them before returning.

Comment: @HaoZhang Benchmark and see. It will certainly be more elegant to use ArrayLists, but there will be a certain overhead in using an external library. My hunch is that it will neither help much nor hurt much. ArrayList code won't be portable to VBA for the Mac, but for most Excel VBA users that isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using collections to build your sets is an option...

```
Function Generator()
    Dim Arr() As Variant: Arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    Dim PSCol As Collection: Set PSCol = PowerSetCol(Arr)
    Dim SubSet As Collection, SubSetStr As String

    For i = 1 To PSCol.Count
        Set SubSet = PSCol.Item(i)
        SubSetStr = "{"
        For j = 1 To SubSet.Count
            SubSetStr = SubSetStr & SubSet.Item(j) & IIf(j = SubSet.Count, "", ", ")
        Next j
        SubSetStr = SubSetStr & "}"
        Debug.Print SubSetStr
    Next i
End Function

Function PowerSetCol(Arr As Variant) As Collection

    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Dim Temp As New Collection, SubSet As Collection

    For i = 1 To 2 ^ (UBound(Arr) + 1) - 1
        Set SubSet = New Collection
        For n = 0 To UBound(Arr)
            If i And 2 ^ n Then SubSet.Add Arr(n)
        Next n
        Temp.Add SubSet
    Next i
    Set PowerSetCol = Temp
End Function
```

*******   EDIT   ********

Apparently accessing collections through index is more intensive than enumerating through the items. Also; you can't use join directly as stated by @John Coleman but a single line function can be used in it's place.

Hopefully the code below is a more optimal solution

```
Function Generator()
    Dim Arr() As Variant: Arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    Dim PSColl As Collection: Set PSColl = PowerSetColl(Arr)

    Dim Str As String, Coll As Collection, Item As Variant
    For Each Coll In PSColl
        Str = ""
        For Each Item In Coll
            Str = strJoin(", ", Str, CStr(Item))
        Next Item
        Debug.Print "{" & Str & "}"
    Next Coll
End Function

Function PowerSetColl(Arr As Variant) As Collection
    Dim Temp As New Collection, SubSet As Collection
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 2 ^ (UBound(Arr) + 1) - 1
        Set SubSet = New Collection
        For n = 0 To UBound(Arr)
            If i And 2 ^ n Then SubSet.Add Arr(n)
        Next n
        Temp.Add SubSet
    Next i
    Set PowerSetColl = Temp
End Function

Function strJoin(Delimiter As String, Optional Str1 As String, Optional Str2 As String) As String
    strJoin = IIf(IsMissing(Str1) Or Str1 = "", Str2, IIf(IsMissing(Str2) Or Str2 = "", Str1, Str1 & Delimiter & Str2))
End Function
```

Comment: Collections are certainly a natural choice for this (+1). It is a pity that there isn't a built-in method for converting them to arrays or a way to directly use `Join()` on them.