# Creating all possible combinations from multiple sets

Tags: vba, excel, math, combinations

I've limited knowledge in maths so pardon the terms if i'm mistaken.
I need to create all possible combinations from multiple sets with at least 1 item included from that set.

```
 - SetA: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
 - SetB: [a, b, c, d] 
 - SetC: [!, @, #, $, %]
```

Example Output:

```
 - [1,a,!]
 - [1,2,a,c,@]
 - [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a,b,c,d,!,@,#,$,%]
```

Is there a specific combination formula for this since i can only come up with nested loops and i'm not sure if it is even correct.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hi @Stedy I'm currently using VBA in excel

Comment: You could compute the power set of the union of the three sets and then use rejection sampling to reject those elements of the power set that don't contain at least one member of each set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@barrycarter had good idea of obtaining the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). However, we don't need to reject anything as we are not getting the power set of the union of sets (this would end up being inefficient as there will be many rejects as the number of sets grows). We simply get the power set of each set, then get all combinations of those power sets. The subroutine below, works for an arbitrary number sets of arbitrary length.

```
Sub CreateAllCombs()

Dim ArrayOfPowSets() As Variant, mySet() As Variant, ArrCounter() As Long, myPS As Variant
Dim myCombs() As Variant, nextComb() As Variant, ParentComb() As Variant, ArrMax() As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, count1 As Long, count2 As Long, CombExist As Boolean
Dim tempCol As Long, myMax As Long, maxRow As Long, totalCombs As Long

   With ActiveSheet
        maxRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

   ReDim ArrayOfSets(1 To maxRow, 1 To 1)
   ReDim ArrCounter(1 To maxRow)
   ReDim ArrMax(1 To maxRow)
   myMax = 0

    For i = 1 To maxRow
        With ActiveSheet
            tempCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With
        ReDim mySet(1 To tempCol)
        For j = 1 To tempCol: mySet(j) = Cells(i, j): Next j
        myPS = PowerSet(mySet)
        ArrMax(i) = UBound(myPS)
        If ArrMax(i) > myMax Then
            myMax = ArrMax(i)
            ReDim Preserve ArrayOfPowSets(1 To maxRow, 1 To ArrMax(i))
        End If
        For j = 1 To ArrMax(i)
            ArrayOfPowSets(i, j) = myPS(j)
        Next j
        ArrCounter(i) = 1
    Next i

    CombExist = True
    totalCombs = 0

    Do While CombExist
        count1 = 1
        ReDim ParentComb(1 To 1)

        For i = 1 To maxRow - 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(ArrayOfPowSets(i, ArrCounter(i)))
                ReDim Preserve ParentComb(1 To count1)
                ParentComb(count1) = ArrayOfPowSets(i, ArrCounter(i))(j)
                count1 = count1 + 1
            Next j
        Next i

        For i = 1 To ArrMax(maxRow)
            count2 = count1
            nextComb = ParentComb
            For j = 1 To UBound(ArrayOfPowSets(maxRow, i))
                ReDim Preserve nextComb(1 To count2)
                nextComb(count2) = ArrayOfPowSets(maxRow, i)(j)
                count2 = count2 + 1
            Next j
            totalCombs = totalCombs + 1
            ReDim Preserve myCombs(1 To totalCombs)
            myCombs(totalCombs) = nextComb
        Next i

        k = maxRow - 1

        Do While (ArrCounter(k) >= ArrMax(k))
            ArrCounter(k) = 1
            k = k - 1
            If k = 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        If k > 0 Then ArrCounter(k) = ArrCounter(k) + 1 Else CombExist = False

    Loop

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    For i = 1 To totalCombs
        For j = 1 To UBound(myCombs(i))
            Cells(i, j) = myCombs(i)(j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

I used a slightly modified version of the power set function written by John Coleman found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086586/4408538)

```
Function PowerSet(Items As Variant) As Variant

    Dim PS As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    Dim subset() As Variant

    n = UBound(Items)
    ReDim PS(1 To 1 + 2 ^ n - 2)
    For i = 1 To 2 ^ n - 1
        ReDim subset(1 To n)
        k = 0
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            If i And 2 ^ j Then
                k = k + 1
                subset(k) = Items(j + 1)
            End If
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve subset(1 To k)
        PS(i) = subset
    Next i

    PowerSet = PS

End Function
```

This assumes that `SetA` is on row 1, `SetB` is on row 2, etc. Observe:

[image]

Additionally, the reader should be warned that this may take a while as there is over 14 million possible combinations.

```
(2^3 - 1) * (2^5 - 1) * (2^16 - 1) = 7 * 31 * 65535 = 14221095
```

Also, all combinations are written out generically to `Sheet2`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had find another solution since i'm trying to process sets with 7,8, 12 length and that's over 100 million combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found my solution please verify.

First, for each sets, i created all possible combinations and checked the length using the sum of pascal triangle without the null or this formula:

> n!/(r!(n-r)!) - 1

e.g.

SetB: [a, b, c, d] -> [a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,abc,abd,acd,bcd,abcd]

After creating all possible combinations for each sets, I just used product rule

> [SetA] X [SetB] X [SetC]

Which resulted for all possible combinations for:

- multiple items
- multiple sets
- no repeat
- no order

Reference: https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html

EDIT1: checking for amount of combinations per set can also be (2^n)-1 where n= length of set

Comment: How did you do this in Excel?

Comment: There is an easier formula for finding all subsets.... Simply take the number of elements, say _n_, and calculate `2^n - 1`.

Comment: @Enigmativity check Joseph Wood's answer above

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using nested for loops.

```
Sub Hello()
    MsgBox ("Hello, world!")

    Dim arr1
    arr1 = Array("1", "2", "3")

    Dim arr2
    arr2 = Array("a", "b", "c")

    Dim arr3
    arr3 = Array("!", "@", "$")

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(arr2)
            For k = 0 To UBound(arr3)
                MsgBox (arr1(i) & arr2(j) & arr3(k))
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This code uses *exactly one* element from each of the sets, but the questioner wants *at least one* element, meaning *one or more* elements.